# Advanced tc filtering flow map for SFQ queue

Tags: traffic-shaping, tc

I'm trying to change the default filtering for a SFQ to one based on source IP, where each IP goes to a class.

I know I can create a SFQ with more divisors with something like:

```
tc qdisc add ... sfq divisor 512
```

Then I want to send each src up to one different class using something like:

```
tc filter add ... flow map key src addend -192.168.0.0 divisor 256
tc filter add ... flow map key src addend -192.168.4.0 divisor 256
```

The problem, is that the first line will send 192.168.0.x traffic to class 1-256 but the second line will also send traffic from 192.168.4.0 to classes 1-256.

Is there anyway to set an offset? I've been checking bitwise operators, but I'm sure it can be achieved.

I know I could just use a hash like:

```
tc filter add ... flow hash keys src divisor 512
```

But, as the source IP address would be hashed, different src IPs could end in the same queue, instead of each one per queue.

This shaping will be installed in a high performance router (20gbps) with 5120 different src IPs, so I cannot really set up one queue per IP or setup plenty of filters, that's why I'm trying to find a more optimal way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you maybe able to obtain the result you desire by using a filter and `nfct-src` to direct packets to queues based on source IP address.  You can also add a filter mask to address your issue of more than 256 queues.

```
tc filter add dev $dev parent $class_index: handle 1 flow divisor 256 map key nfct-src and 0xff
```

Comment: Yeah, but AFAIK it will use a src ip hash to place IPs in flows, there is no guarantee each IP will end in a specific flow. Meaning there could be several IPs which hash to the same queue.